# Where is AccountManager in Amazon Kindle HDX?

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager, kindle-fire

I have implemented the `AccountManager` workflow to add accounts to my service in the standard Android settings screen.

In typical Android devices, I successfully get my App's icon, settings, login workflow, etc. in the "Accounts" section of the settings screen, and I am able to add accounts.

However, in an Amazon Kindle HDX, even though the API exists, and in my App details I can see the permissions are identified (`android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS`, ...), I can't find the AccountManager anywhere in the settings screen. Everything seems related to Amazon authentication. The closest thing is "**Social Network Accounts**" under "**My Account**", but only displays Facebook and Twitter, and seems a proprietary account manager rather than Android's.

Does anybody know if

- The standard Account list exists in Kindle HDX?
- The AccountManager API is the way to go? or shall I write a custom account dialog in case the App is running on a Kindle?

Regarding the second question, Amazon claims the API is supported https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=906 but if accounts can't be listed or managed, I suppose it's better to use a proprietary approach. Am I wrong?